# dynamically generated html5 audio playlist

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to create a kind of HTML5 audio player with a dynamically changing playlist that will be created from a database paths - links randomly generated through a PHP script. I was searching around and combined all info I could gather with an idea I had, but it ain't working. This is basically the script to run when a user has picked a music category (tag):

```
<?php
session_start();
include('sdp/app_const.php');
$dbc=mysql_connect(host, user, pass);
$db_select=mysql_select_db(database);

$tag=$_GET['tag'];

$q_select="SELECT * FROM songs WHERE tag='".$tag."'";
$result=mysql_query($q_select);

$tragoudia=array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($tragoudia, $row['path']);
    }


function song() {
    $tuxaio=array_rand($tragoudia, 1);
    return $tragoudia[$tuxaio];
}
```

?>

and on the HTML part of the file:

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay controls src='audio/'<?php return song(); ?>'.mp3' type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("ended",function() {
    this.src = <?php return song(); ?>;
    this.play();
    });
```

Any thoughts perhaps?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **ain't working** care to expand, just a little

Comment: when the browser loads the page it, the <audio> controls aren't there, and I am only receiving `<audio id="audio" <br="" src="audio/" controls="" autoplay="">` inside the <body>.

Comment: `<?php return song(); ?>;` `return` should be `echo`

Comment: now that was an improvement, at least now my header, footer etc are showing up, but still get a <br /> as this.src in my javascript